# Unity - MRTK - HoloLens: Modify Collider of 2D-Buttons so the Cursor gets closer

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, mrtk

My current problem is that the cursor appears too far away from a button. You can see in the screenshot what I mean. Hovering over a button from the list lookes like this:
[image]

**Question:** What can I do so the cursor get closer to the button, because on the HoloLens you see the distance?

Looking somewhere else on the canvas except the buttons, the cursor gets closer:
[image]

**--Edit--**
I should mention that the scene has a scaled cube (the gray thing in the screenshot) and in front of that a world canvas (white thing), which contains the scrollview/list.

Comment: yep, confirmed I see the same behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw the same behaviour for UI elements.

**I can only provide you a workaround.** It is a bit hacky but it works:

1. Go through **all** UI elements especially `Text` and `Image` and disable the option `RayCast Target`.

   [image]

   This makes the Cursor be sitting right on top of them ... **but** you will notice your `Button`s are now non-responsive and you can not interact with them anymore.

   [image]

   This happens because the Physics system requires either a RayCastTarget or a `Collider` in order to fire it's pointer events like e.g. `PointerEnter`, `PointerDown` etc.
2. Therefore now add a `BoxCollider` (**not** `BoxCollider2D`!) to your `Button`s and scale it to the correct size. It looks like you are using a `VerticalLayoutGroup` so you can simply correct the positioning of the `BoxCollider` by setting the `RectTransform` to centered once (the `VerticalLayoutgroup` will anyway re-enforce the Top-Left anchoring). In my case the `BoxCollider` needs with `0.8` and height `0.1` ... and for the `z` I choose `0.01` but it can be smaller if you whish

   [image]

Hurray, now the buttons are interactable again and the Cursor only has it's usual distance + the half of the choosen `z` thikness of the `BoxColliders`.

[image]

Since the Background cube has it's own `BoxCollider` anyway we don't need to add further `Colliders` for the `ScrollView` and UI panels.

**You might have to add some though for the ScrollBars as well if you need them!**

---

As said this is more like a quick workaround and might not be a final solution since whenever a size of the `Button` or the `ScrollRect` is changed you have to rework those hardcoded `BoxCollider` dimesnions as well ...

Comment: Yes, I also just realized unchecking the `Raycast Target` is fixing this, but didn't think about the `Box Colliders`. If at the end of my project I won't have a better solution Im gonna use this one. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue on 3D objects. This could happen because the objects collider definition. I mean, you can import a render mesh but the mesh collider could be different (bigger, smaller, ...)

I hope this solves your problem ;)

Comment: on normal 3d object u have certainly an collider. But this are 2D-Button from Unity, you cant access the collider of that kind of button. What @derHugo did is, that he added some colliders as a kind of workaround

Comment: Oh, ok. I though you created from 0 your buttons. My bad, sorry :(